How do I change sample rate of audio from 48k to 24k?
I am currently not able to change the microphone sample rate from 48k to 24k on Linux. My distro is Ubuntu. I have installed pulseaudio to change the config. Any other framework for changing this is also much appreciated.
I have tried several things.

I downloaded pulseaudio and changed the config file here to /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

When I run pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'index:' -e 'name:' -e 'sample spec:' it still shows 48000.

When I check the config using pulseaudio --dump-conf it shows 24000. What should I do to change the sample rate?



What version of Ubuntu are you using?

arecord -f S24_LE -d 25 -r 24000 --device="hw:1,0" /tmp/test-mic.wav
